# Shift Register reacting to shiftout function incorrectly

Tags: c++, c, arduino-uno

I am new to this shift register. So i created a online simulation of the shift register that hook up to 8 LEDs, the ol' 8bit translate to 8 LED experiment. My design is that when i entered a character like "a" into the serial monitor, it will show in the result in code like 100000, and it should shown in the LEDs too(the sixth LED should light up).

```
char character;
byte input = 0b01;

void setup() {
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  byte input = 0b01;
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    character = Serial.read();
    if (character == 'a') {
      Serial.print("character received: ");
      Serial.println(character);
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        updateShiftRegister(input);
        input = input << 1;
        delay(100);
      }

      Serial.print("Input: ");
      Serial.print(input, BIN);
      Serial.println();
    } else {
      Serial.print("Please retry.\n");
    }
  }
}

void updateShiftRegister(byte input) {
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, input);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
}
```

Problem is when i run the thing, the result is alright but the shift register in the simulation is wack. Every LEDs turn on,

[image: LEDs]

I found the shiftout function is main cause of this, any idea why it is causing every LED to light up?

Comment: I suspect without the hardware it's going to be difficult for us to help. Consider simplifying your code. Do you need the for loop to get the incorrect behavior? Are you ever able to get it to show just one LED?

Comment: This should be tagged as c++ and arduino?

Comment: Looks like `shiftOut` shifts out the whole byte for you, so you don't need your own loop to handle all bits in the byte.

Comment: https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/communication/guide-to-shift-out